# App doesn't open when Flash is On ( App contains flash related codes )

Tags: android, android-camera

I was testing the Flashlight status, by opening the camera and check for torch, And this way is the best and the only working way, So the app i'm testing checks for Flashlist status, When pressed, it enables the Flashlight, and it disables the Flashlight, If i enabled the flashlight and exited the app, and re-opened it and disabled the Flashlight, nothing strange ( errors happen ).

BUT, If i enabled the flashlight out from my app ( from SystemUI quick toggles, or another app ) and tried to open my app, it doesn't open, until i disable the flashlight from where i enabled it, and re-try to open the app.

Here's my code to check for status :

```
public static boolean isFlashLightEnabled()
{
    boolean Enabled = false;
    if (camera == null) {
        camera = Camera.open();
        camera.startPreview();
        Camera.Parameters parameter = camera.getParameters();
        Log.d("LOG", (parameter.getFlashMode().equalsIgnoreCase("torch")) ? "Torch" : "No Torch");
        Enabled = parameter.getFlashMode().equalsIgnoreCase("torch");

    }
    if (camera != null) {
        Camera.Parameters parameter = camera.getParameters();
        Log.d("LOG", (parameter.getFlashMode().equalsIgnoreCase("torch")) ? "Torch" : "No Torch");
        Enabled = parameter.getFlashMode().equalsIgnoreCase("torch");
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
    }

    return Enabled;
}
```

In short, I can't open the app when flash is enabled by external source .

Comment: Might be that external app is using the Camera, and didn't release it yet, that's why my app is crashing ?

Comment: Yes that's what I thought. Did you debug and check?

Comment: W/CameraBase: An error occurred while connecting to camera:
And then VM shutting down.

Comment: Looks like the same problem what we thought of. Try handling that situation then.